# How can I change my alchemy specialisation?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

My alchemy specialisation is currently Transmutation Master and I would like to change this to one of the other specialisations.

Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes thats easy. Open your spellbook, go to professions, you will see a red button next to your specialization that allows you to unlearn your current spec. You then visit your trainer and have the specialization quests offered all over again.

Its the same with all professions by the way, for future reference.

Comment: Does this have any downsides? Costs money or such?

Comment: @F.S. the downsides are getting the mats for each different quest that is offered. The money cost is minimal, I think 10 gold.